# Why does $|e^{cos2t+isin2t}|=|e^{cos2t}|$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In an exercise we came to the expression:

$$|e^{e^{2it}}|$$ where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$

Now I know that  $$|e^{e^{2it}}|=|e^{cos2t+isin2t}|$$  by euler's formula.

But the next equation I did not understand   $$|e^{cos2t+isin2t}|=|e^{cos2t}|$$

Is because $$|e^{cos2t+isin2t}|=|e^{cos2t}e^{isin2t}|=|e^{cos2t}|\cdot|e^{isin2t}|$$

Using euler's formula again on $|e^{isin2t}|$ we get $$|e^{isin2t}|=|e^{cos(sin2t)+isin(sin2t)}|$$

So we left to show that $|{cos(sin2t)+isin^2(2t)}|=0$?

Comment: Is $t$ real, imaginary, or complex?

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle e^{e^{2it}}$?

Comment: Note that $|e^{ix}|=1$ for all x

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen forgot added to the qeustion

Comment: Your last use of Euler's formula seems incorrect. $e^{i\sin(2t)} = \cos(\sin(2t))+i\sin(\sin(2t))$ (not raised to an exponent).

Comment: @Khosrotash, all *real* $x$.

Comment: @tilper precisely, hence my comment above. Because the OP edited to note that $t \in [0,2\pi]$ we can safely say that $t$ is real

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, I know, but Khosrotash wasn't talking about that $t$ (or at least not obviously talking about it) since they said $x$ and not $t$.  And while $x$ is typically used to denote real variables, such distinctions need to be clearly and carefully made in expressions like $|e^{ix}|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last equation
$$|e^{i\sin 2t}|=|e^{\cos(\sin 2t)+i\sin(\sin 2t)}|$$
is incorrect; instead, it should be
$$|e^{i\sin 2t}|=|\cos(\sin 2t)+i\sin(\sin 2t)|=\cos^2(\sin 2t)+\sin^2(\sin 2t)=1.$$
In fact, the same proof shows that $|e^{ix}|=1$ for all real $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$ \lvert e^{x+iy} \rvert = \sqrt{e^{x+iy}\overline{e^{x+iy}}} = \sqrt{ e^{x+iy}e^{x-iy} } = \sqrt{e^{2x}} = e^{x} $$
since $e^x>0$. So $\lvert e^{z} \rvert = e^{\Re(z)}$ for any complex number $z$.

Comment: Simple and beautiful, did not think about this, thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$|e^{\cos2t+i\sin2t}|=|e^{\cos2t}|\cdot|e^{i\sin2t}|$$

Now for real $t$ use Euler identity $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of a more general fact: that for all $\theta$, $e^{i\theta}$ has norm $1$.

Given this, note that $e^{\cos 2t + i\sin 2t}$ is just $e^{\cos 2t}e^{i\sin 2t}$, which has norm $\vert e^{\cos 2t}\vert$.

Answer (score 1):

For a complex number $z$ in polar form $re^{i\theta}$, then $|z|=r$

With $z=e^{\cos2t+i\sin2t}$, the polar form immediately yields $r=e^{\cos2t}$

(The modulus sign in your question is redundant since the exponential function is always positive
i.e.
$|e^{\cos2t}|=e^{\cos2t}$)

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
|e^{x+iy}|=|e^xe^{iy}|=|e^x||e^{iy}|=e^x
$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ (since $e^{iy}$ is a point on the unit circle).